# Test for UK holiday not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Maybe I missing something obvious but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Im trying to write a function which returns true if a given date is a UK holiday.

Ive created a small array to test my function:

```
const holidays = [
new Date(2016, 0, 1),  //NewYearsDay
new Date(2016, 2, 25),  //GoodFriday
new Date(2016, 2, 27),  //Easter
];
```

Then my function is

```
function isHoliday(date){
    return holidays.some(function(d) {
        return (d == date);
    });
}
```

To test it I ran

```
 date = new Date(2016, 0, 1);
 var a = isHoliday(date);
 alert(a);
```

But the alert says false ??

Comment: Two objects, e.g. Dates, aren't equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test two Date objects for equality.
Just test the date's timestamps which is a numeric value

```
function isHoliday(date){
    return holidays.some(function(d) {
        return (d.getTime() == date.getTime());
    });
}
```